# SSIS Variable- Evaluating Expression Taking Time in Script Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, msbi, script-task

I have a Variable which uses another variable to get its value. I had set the EvaluateAsExpression property to True. Now when I use this variable in a **Script task** it is taking 2-3 Minutes to evaluate that expression. But if I Hard Code the variable value instead of reading it from another variable then it is finishing in less than a Second. Anyone let me know if I am missing anything ? I am using BIDS/SSIS 2008

```
Variable1: D:\app\srikar.mogaliraju
Variable2: @[User::Variable1]+"\\Product"
```

Script Task Code:

```
        public void Main()
        {

            String SourceFolderPath, DestinationFolderpath;
            SourceFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::Variable2"].Value.ToString();

//Random Code
 Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Variable 2 Expression Builder:
[image]

Comment: What is the expression it? But I would say the machine it is running on is under-powered.

Comment: @Arthur Added the expression in my question.

Comment: @Arthur When I use this Evaluated Variable in other tasks except Script task, it is working with out any problem. I am facing the problem only with script task.

Comment: That's a slowness on the parser end. Looks like it takes longer for it to get inside the Script Task than any other

Comment: @Arthur Any suggestions to perform a Trail and Error to make it faster?

Comment: Set it up outside the *Script Task* @Srikar

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju Why are you using a script task to set another package variable's value. You can do this in the Package Variables Expressions property. This is both easier and simpler.

Comment: @JWeezy I am not setting it in the Script task. I am just using the Variable whose value is set in the Package Variables Expressions property.

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju It might be more helpful if you post the script task code so we can look at it and try to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @JWeezy Edited my question to add Script Task code and Variable 2 Expression Builder.  The problem is at the reading of variable value in Script task.

Comment: Are you sure that the delay is on the line where the expression is being calculated and not elsewhere? Simple string concatenation shouldn't yield problems. Maybe it's the rest of the code in the script. Do you have parallel executions?

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju Are you trying to perform an expression evaluation in the script task? If yes, that is wrong. You perform variable Expression Evaluation in the Variables window. You then select those variables in the Script Task UI for either ReadOnly or ReadWrite.

Comment: @EzLo I am sure it is because of the expression being calculated. I kept a break point their to confirm the same. if i remove the expression builder and hard code the value of the variable, there is not issue at all.

Comment: @JWeezy I am performing the expression evaluation in Variables windown. Edited my question with a screenshot for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got any solution for this. So posting the answer with the solution I implemented to bypass this problem.

1. Use ExecuteSqlTask to read Variable1 and Append "\Product" to Variable1 value.Set the result set property to Single Row.
2. Assign the Result Set to Variable2 and use this Variable in Script task.